# how to get an html anchor effect with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a click handler, which has "event.preventDefault". There is whole lot of logic that occurs within this function. At the end of this logic i would like the page to scroll up to the top. ie the same effect as an anchor. ie "

```
    $('.vod-playlist-film a').bind("click", function(event) {

    // some logic
    // now i need the browser to goto the top of the page

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi & Andy. Works great. Seemed fine in Chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).scrollTop(0);
```

should do the work.

Comment: Safari and maybe Chrome seem to get nervous about using the body like that, so it may be necessary to wrap the page in a dummy `<div>` (or one of those trendy new HTML5 elements).